# Ayuda con aunentificación y real Time data base firebase

Tags: firebase, angular7

necesito de su ayuda si es posible, tengo un proyecto en el cual me autentico con firebase y mi base de datos en el real time database

el tema es que tengo los siguientes 2 usuarios distintos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y mi base de datos es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero que el usuario1 solo pueda acceder a bodega 1 y usuario2 pueda acceder bodega 1 y bodega 2

utilizo angular 7 y no tengo problema en el login y manejo bien el API rest con el real time data base, pero no puedo relacionar usuarios con los datos de la base de dato, y no entiendo muy bien da documentacion de firebase

alguien que me pueda orientar a resolver este problema

gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hace tiempo tuve un problema similar, no se si es lo que buscas pero si quieres obtener los datos de una bodega con un usuario en especifico podrías cambiar la estructura de tu base de datos con el id del usuario como identificador.

[image: forma1]

o también de esta forma

[image: forma2]

y así cuando trabajes con la base de datos tengas como referencia el id del usuario

Comment: Me ha ayudado bastante tu respuesta te cuento ahora [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7Mfl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7Mfl.png) como puedes ver he creado con uid del login y luego empresa y he creado 2 empresas, pero estas empresas solo lo puede leer el usuario1 pero el usuario2 no, siguiendo el arbol que hice solo el usuario1 puede leerlo y nadie mas. sabes como puedo hacer para que el usuario 2 pueda leer la misma información sin replicar la información de empresa? gracias

Comment: mueve esta respuesta a la pregunta. Puedes usar la segunda opción que te dio crisfar pero con una lista de usuarios en vez de un único usuario